# Array not outputting in modal

Tags: angularjs

I can't figure out why the content in my array isn't outputting in the modal.
I'm doing a ng-repeat. the buttons are pulling from the array, but the content inside the modal is blank. Can anyone tell me whey?

Here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8s9ss/203/

```
<div ng-app="app">

       <div ng-controller="RecipeController">  
        <div ng-repeat="recipe in ChickenRecipes">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">{{ recipe.name }}</button> <br />

                <!--MODAL WINDOW--> 
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3>Recipe: {{ recipe.name }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                          Recipe Content<br />

                            {{ recipe.cookTime }}
                            {{recipe.directions}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                    </div>
                </script>

        </div>  
        </div>


</div>
```

Comment: your modal has a different scope

Comment: If it's all in the same controller, wouldn't that make it the same scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$modal` create a child scope (and default is child of `$rootScope`) for the modal

So what you need is something like this:

```
$scope.open = function (recipe) {
    $scope.recipe = recipe;
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      scope: $scope,
    });
};
```

And:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(recipe)">{{ recipe.name }}</button> <br />
```

P/s: It's better to use `$modal`'s `resolve` and `controller` option (pass the resolved data to the new controller)

Comment: This is also a great example that I tested and works. Thanks for showing me this. This is a great reference for the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up some concepts, putting the modal template inside the `ng-repeat` won't do a thing. That's not how modals work.

First, remove the template from the `ng-repeat` and put it elsewhere.

Then, you must create a controller for your modal:

```
app.controller('RecipeModalController', function($scope, $modalInstance, $modal, item){
    $scope.recipe = item;
    console.log(item);
});
```

And pass the recipe you want to open as a parameter on `ng-click`:

```
$scope.open = function (recipe) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        controller: 'RecipeModalController',
        resolve: {item: function() {return recipe} },
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    });
};
```

I've updated the fiddle to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/8s9ss/204/

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and demo. I'll be using this as a reference for the future